# Passing a nested Dictionary to web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using a Post method to send data to a web API. Something like this:

```
string apiUrl = serviceAddress;
var client = new HttpClient();
var DObject = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"UserId", UserID},
    {"Type", "109" },
    {"Id", templateID},
    {"Subject", subjectofEmail},
    {"Data", @"'Name','Payman','Family','Payman'"}
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(DObject);
var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
```

The problem is that, the Data object is also a dictionary. So, I have problem sending data. What is the solution?

Comment: Nice, what is the problem?

Comment: Is the API developed by you? If not what the documentation of the API says?

Comment: I have no documentation about the service.

Comment: Is there any problem in the Data part of my object? Or Have to change it?

Comment: How do you know that the service expects a dictionary and it has nested dictionary too? It looks like s class which you need to have with proper properties and serialize it to json? Which is that service provide who doesn't provide documentation of the service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [httpclient post nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089861/httpclient-post-nested-dictionary)