# httpclient post nested dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, httpclient

I'm having an error :

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,
>   string>>`

When I am posting nested dictionary using `HttpClient`

```
var arg_employee = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "filter_data",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"user_name", "admin"},
        }
    },
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(arg_employee);
// ... Use HttpClient.
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uRL, content))
using (HttpContent responseContent = response.Content)
{
    // ... Read the string.
    return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How I can post nested dictionary or array ?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You are sending them as FormUrlEncodedContent. You will be able to send this kind of complex objects as JSON or XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormUrlEncodedContent` accepts `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection` , not `Dictionary`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh158958%28v%3Dvs.118%29)

To pass dictionary you should serialize it to json, for example.

First step, getting json representation of your dictionary using `Newtonsoft.Json` (you can manually serialize it or use another library)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

var arg_employee = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "filter_data",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"user_name", "admin"},
        }
    },
};

var jsonDictionary = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg_employee );
```

Second step, post it as `StringContent` instead of `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonDictionary , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```